# MySQL migration not succesfull (XAMPP)

Tags: mysql, xampp, data-migration

I am moving my website development from one laptop to a new one. I am running XAMPP to run an Apache + MySQL (and a few other things) on my laptops.

I can remember from the previous time I migrated it a couple of years ago, I could just install XAMPP, and copy the database-files in C:\xampp\mysql\data to the new laptop, start the MySQL-service and that was it. So I did that again this time (making sure not to overwrite the "mysql", "performance_schema" and "phpmyadmin"-databases because the versions of the software is different.

However, now I have the weird behaviour that I can access certain tables, but not others in PHPMyAdmin. I get an error:

```
#1932 Table 'databasename.tablename' doesn't exist in Engine
```

When I look in the data-folders, I see that some tables have .MYD and .MYI-files, and some don't. It looks like the ones that do have those files can be seen in PHPMyAdmin, but the others can't.

I tried Googling, but I don't get any solutions that seem to work for me. One for example said that the files iblogfile* and ibdata should also be copied from the old laptop, and that did solve a lot of the problems, but then it started throwing errors that certain tables within phpmyadmin did not exist...

What can I do about this? Is it possible to let the engine rebuild the index (as I suspect it is some kind of index issue), or do I need to do something else? It is quite an extensive set of databases (68 excluding the three aforementioned "mysql", "performance_schema" and "phpmyadmin"-databases). I don't know if that makes a difference?